# Retrieve data from SharePoint list via PnP JS and CAML Query

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, caml-query, pnp, react

I wanted to display all files which have the property "Job" = "Job1".

How to retrieve list view items using PnP JS and CAML Query?

Here is the CAML Query?

```
   <ViewFields>
      <FieldRef Name='Job' />
      <FieldRef Name='FileRef' />
      <FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef' />
      <FieldRef Name='ParentUniqueId' />
   </ViewFields>
   <QueryOptions>
      <ViewAttributes Scope='RecursiveAll' />
      <Lists ServerTemplate='101' />
   </QueryOptions>
   <Where>
      <And>
         <And>
            <And>
               <Eq>
                  <FieldRef Name='job' />
                  <Value Type='MultiChoice'>Job1</Value>
               </Eq>
               <Eq>
                  <FieldRef Name='lastName' LookupId='True' />
                  <Value Type='Lookup'>1</Value>
               </Eq>
            </And>
            <Eq>
               <FieldRef Name='LastName2' LookupId='True' />
               <Value Type='Lookup'>1</Value>
            </Eq>
         </And>
         <Eq>
            <FieldRef Name='FSObjType' />
            <Value Type='Integer'>0</Value>
         </Eq>
      </And>
   </Where>
```

Comment: Do you have issue with getting correct CAML query or getting items using PnPJS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have figured out the correct CAML query for your requirements then you can get items from SharePoint using a CAML Query like below:

```
import { ICamlQuery } from "@pnp/sp/lists";

// build the caml query object (in this example, we include Title field and limit rows to 5)
const caml: ICamlQuery = {
    ViewXml: "<View><ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title' /></ViewFields><RowLimit>5</RowLimit></View>",
};

// get list items
const r = await list.getItemsByCAMLQuery(caml);

// log resulting array to console
console.log(r);
```

**Reference**:

[Get list items using a CAML Query](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/lists/#get-list-items-using-a-caml-query).